# obtain actions from ecb

Tags: 2010, list, custom-actions

is there a way how to obtain the default list of custom actions in ECB ? I tried `list.UserCustomActions` but it returns only custom actions added by user. In my case it returned 0. I would like to obtain custom actions like Edit, View CustomAction objects. I using SPGridView and I would like to make o copy of them because the data come from search engine. I would like to this look close to list view.  It is possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you properly, you want ECB for your list, if yes then you don't need to copy default ones but just this code to create a new ECB column and add it to SPGridView,

```
      SPMenuField colMenu = new SPMenuField();
      colMenu.HeaderText = "Presenter Name";
      colMenu.TextFields = "PresenterName";
      colMenu.MenuTemplateId = "PresenterListMenu";
      colMenu.NavigateUrlFields = "ID,PresenterName";
      colMenu.NavigateUrlFormat = "do.aspx?p={0}&q={1}";
      colMenu.TokenNameAndValueFields = "EDIT=ID,NAME=PresenterName";
      colMenu.SortExpression = "PresenterName";
      this.Controls.Add(presenterListMenu);
      oGrid.Columns.Add(colMenu);
```

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powlo/archive/2007/02/25/displaying-custom-data-through-sharepoint-lists-using-spgridview-and-spmenufield.aspx)

Don't think you can get default ones, you might need to re-create them, here's the [tutorial](http://www.devexpertise.com/2009/02/25/integrating-a-custom-aspnet-application-into-sharepoint-part-2/).